# NestJS class validator to check if text does NOT contain an url

Tags: regex, validation, nestjs, class-validator

For a chat that i'm making, I want to check if the incoming message does **not** contain any links or urls. I have the following DTO set up:

```js
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Matches, MaxLength } from 'class-validator';

    export class CreateMessageInput {
      @ApiProperty()
      userId: string;
    
      @ApiProperty()
      @MaxLength(200)
      @Matches(
        '^(?!.*\b(?:https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]).*$',
      )
      text: string;
    }
```

This however does not do anything, I can send urls just fine. What can I do here to make it reject messages with an url?

Comment: I'm no expert in nestjs, so don't how plausible your idea. But your regex lacks `a-z` in both symbol classes. And more generally I doubt that those classes are even needed: wouldn't check for protocol be enough?

Comment: Additionally, what are expecting to happen to non-ASCII domains, like сайт.рф?

Comment: @markalex im pretty much looking for regex that checks for the protocols indeed, but also things like test.com. Im not sure how to tackle that one though

Comment: In that case you'll have problems. Because on one hand something like `13.ford` is valid domain, if I'm not mistaken, and on the other hand it is simply thirteenth ford in Latvian.

Comment: And even more generously, you'll cause a great trouble to your users, if your app wouldn't allow simple typo of missing space after dot in the sentence's end.In most cases it will result in something very similar to url. (see what I've done here?). Wouldn't you believe: it is even existing domain, though it returns 403(

Comment: @markalex good points, I agree. So it might be better to just check for the http(s) protocol?

Comment: It depends on your ultimate goal. If it is just 'I'd like .., because I want' - use simple protocol detection.  If there's some good reasoning behind this idea - you the only one who can weigh in all pros and cons.

Comment: @markalex the goal is to make sure that people in a public chatroom are not able to send scam links

Answer (score 2):

First, create a new file called not-url.validator.ts in your project.

Import the necessary modules and create the custom validator.

```js
import { ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface, ValidationArguments } from 'class-validator';
import * as url from 'url';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'notUrl', async: false })
export class NotUrlValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {

  validate(text: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
    // Parse the input text as a URL
    const parsedUrl = url.parse(text);

    // Check if the URL protocol is either "http" or "https"
    if (parsedUrl.protocol === 'http:' || parsedUrl.protocol === 'https:') {
      return false; // Input contains a URL
    }
    
    return true; // Input does NOT contain a URL
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return 'Text must not contain a URL';
  }
}
```

Now, you can use the NotUrlValidator in your DTOs or other class validator decorators. For example:

```js
import { IsString, Validate } from 'class-validator';
import { NotUrlValidator } from './not-url.validator';

export class MyDto {
  @IsString()
  @Validate(NotUrlValidator)
  text: string;
}
```

Comment: I recommend adding a bit more description about what's going on in your code. Also, I'm no expert, but it seems to me, that this validator will only prevent messages that consist only from a single link, whereas OP look to limit messages to contain a link.

Comment: Additionally, if I understand [this](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlparseurlstring-parsequerystring-slashesdenotehost) correctly - `url.parse` is deprecated.

Comment: I think the nestJS part of this would work, the parsing is indeed not what im looking for, since a user can send 200 characters out of which i want to check if it contains ANY urls